# Using Unison with colordiff

Tags: diff, less, unison

I want Unison to show the diffs with `colordiff`.

I’ve got `diff = colordiff -u CURRENT2 CURRENT1 | less -R` in my config file but it seems like `Unison` pipes the output to plain `less` nonetheless, so I get raw escape sequences instead.

Comment: Can you change to any other diff utility via the Unison config?

Comment: `diff = colordiff -u CURRENT2 CURRENT1 | less -R` … Which, as the root of the problem, doesn’t work.

Comment: I am asking whether you are successful in configuring Unison to use any *other* diff utility than `diff = colordiff -u CURRENT2 CURRENT1 | less -R`, e.g. meld, in trying to help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: `Meld` works like a charm, but is a little over-the-top for the job.

Comment: What happens if you skip the pipe to `less`, e.g. if you only specify `colordiff` to Unison?

Comment: Exactly the same. When using meld I also have to quit out of less after closing meld.

Comment: You might want to try post to [unison-users](http://marc.info/?l=unison-users&r=1&w=2) and report back here if you find a solution.